# Extending codeigniter form_validation class returns undefined

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a simple class extending `CI_Form_validation class` and placed it in `application\libraries\MY_Form_validation.php`. Here's the code inside the file :

```
<?php

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {


    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function uniquekey($str){

       if($str == 'anda'){
          $this->form_validation->set_message('uniquekey', "The category name has been used");
          return false;
       } else {
          return true;
       }
    }
}

?>
```

and in another class named `Category`, I did `$this->load->library('form_validation');` and used the callback function above when validating an input text box.

However, when I tried to submit the form, the server returned two boxes of error, first error says :

```
Message: Undefined property: MY_Form_validation::$form_validation
Filename: libraries/MY_Form_validation.php
```

And the second error says :

```
Message: Call to a member function set_message() on null
Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/onesource_reboot/application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php
```

What have I done wrong in my code? I read from [here](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/02/server-side-form-validations-using-php.html) and are using codeigniter version 3.0.4

---

I've finally made it, thanks to [narf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468027/narf) and [devpro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172798/devpro), when I insert the word 'anda' and submit the form, the form validation will return false and show the desired error message.
I tried a bit more complex validation which involving database interaction. I added this line in my constructor, still on the same class :

```
public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
    $this->CI->load->database();

}
```

and changed my `uniquekey` function into this :

```
public function uniquekey($str){

    $this->CI->db->select('CategoryName');
    $this->CI->db->where('CategoryName', $str);
    $result = $this->CI->db->get('category');
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $this->set_message('uniquekey', 'Kategori telah terpakai');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

And submitted the form, here's the result I got :

```
Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Kategori.(uniquekey)
```

Now what?

---

Solved.
I don't know if it's a bug, but here's what I did to make it work.

```
public function uniquekey($str){

    $this->CI->db->select('CategoryName');
    $this->CI->db->where('CategoryName', $str);
    $result = $this->CI->db->get('category');
    $numrows = $result->num_rows();

    if(numrows > 0) {
        $this->set_message('uniquekey', 'Kategori telah terpakai');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not checking the condition, you are assigning the value here:

```
if($str = 'anda'){
```

**This should be:**

```
if($str == 'anda'){
```

> = sign is use to assign the values 
>   == sign is use to compare the values

Comment: This does solve a valid problem, but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @AnggieAriWidhia: chose the best answer and mark as accepted.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: got another problem, could you help me with that again?

Comment: @AnggieAriWidhia:where r u using this callback fucntion uniquekey() ?? this value is not matched Kategori

Comment: I'm using this callback function inside the `MY_Form_validation`. Now it's solved

Answer (score 1):

You use `$this->form_validation` only from inside controllers and/or models.

When you are inside the library itself, you're in a different scope, where the `form_validation` property doesn't exist ... and you don't need it in the first place - you just use `$this`, so it's `$this->set_message()` instead of `$this->form_validation->set_message()`.

Read up on how OOP works: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: I thought it was parent::set_message() because I'm extending parent's functions. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: got another problem, could you help me with that again?

Comment: You're not supposed to add more and more questions to your original one ... Open a new one instead.